# Change Entire URL of Current Page in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that replaces the new tab page where the user can select what they want their new tab page to look like. The extension will execute the following code to set the URL of the html file to redirect the new tab page to:

```
  chrome.storage.sync.get("setPage", function(items) {
  setTab = items.setPage;

  chrome.tabs.query({
      active: true,
      currentWindow: true
  }, function(tabs) {

      var active = tabs[0].id;

      chrome.tabs.update(active, {
          url: "dist/html/" + setTab + ".html"
      }, function() {});
  });
```

});

My problem is that the address bar will display the URL of the html file, such as `chrome-extension://ogdgmnoeidhhookfgmaaookkocplfflh/dist/html/[page].html`. It also will display the name of the extension where the green " Secure" normally appears.

**How do I clear the address bar, and make it blank?**

Comment: The only method is use [newtab override page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) (see a sample extension linked there).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. It isn't an option because I have multiple pages. I can't edit the manifest.json programmatically, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a full-page iframe.

I set my override page as a html file with a full page iframe. The extension will change the src of the iframe onload to the correct  html file.

Not the most elegant solution, but it works.